# How do I ask user for inputs to a bool in C++?

Tags: c++

I am stuck writing a program, where I want the user input to be either 'y' or 'n' to assign to true or false. How do I put 'y' or 'n' for Y to be true and N to be false?
Also, I have no idea why my console outputs after giving the first answer..

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    bool isMale = true;
    bool isTall = false;

    cout << "Are you a male? ";
    cin >> isMale;

    cout << "Are you tall? ";
    cin >> isTall;

    if (isMale && isTall) {
        cout << "You are a tall male";
    }
    else if (isMale && !isTall) {
        cout << "You are a short male";
    }
    else {
        cout << "You are a female";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried putting the user inputs in the 2 variables but I have no idea how to assign letters Y or N to be either true or false to it, so I can finish writing my program.

Comment: `'y'` and `'n'` are `char` not `bool`

Comment: There's no built in mechanism that would interpret `Y` as `true` and `N` as `false`. You have to write the code for that yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You can take a `char` as input and depending on that, you can assign the value to `bool` like this:

```
int main()
{
    char input;
    bool isMale = true;
    bool isTall = false;

    cout << "Are you a male? ";
    cin >> input;
    isMale = (input=='y');

    cout << "Are you tall? ";
    cin >> input;
    isTall = (input=='y');

    if (isMale && isTall) {
        cout << "You are a tall male";
    }
    else if (isMale && !isTall) {
        cout << "You are a short male";
    }
    else {
        cout << "You are a female";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(input=='y')? isMale = true : isMale = false;` is a very convoluted way to say `isMale = (input=='y');`